# Updating DataSource of PivotTables via VBA, without creating new PivotCaches

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a workbook, where there is a RawData sheet and there are 8-9 other sheets that have pivot tables that read a table from RawData. The RawData changes daily, i.e. there can be more or less number of rows in the RawData sheet's table.

Right now, I manually update DataSource property of each pivot table one each sheet using ChangeDataSource feature of Excel. However, this is painful. Crawling on web I found vba code to update all Pivot tables at once. I am not pasting the whole code, but it looks something like this.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=<RawData-AddressRange>)
```

But what this code does is, it creates new pivot caches for each pivot table and increases the size of the file. However, I do not want the file size or number of pivot cache's to increase, but just change the dataSource of existing PivotTables/PivotCaches and refresh them.

Answer (score 1):

To set a single `PivotCache` for all the `PivotTable`:

```vb
Sub UpdatePivots()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, pivot As PivotTable, cache As PivotCache

  ' create a new pivot cache '
  Set cache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
      XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, _
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)

  ' set the pivot cache for each pivot table
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pivot In ws.PivotTables
      If cache.Index Then
        pivot.CacheIndex = cache.Index
      Else
        pivot.ChangePivotCache cache
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' refresh the cache
  cache.Refresh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just turn RawData into an Excel Table (Ctrl + T is the keyboard shortcut) and then point your PivotTables at that Table. (You'll have to use the 'Change Data Source' button one more time, to get it to change from using a hard-coded reference like $A$1:$Z$1000 to a Table reference like Table1).

From then on, any time you put new data into RawData, the Table will automatically expand (or contract) to accomodate it, and whenever you click refresh, the PivotTables will automatically reference those Tables instead of a hard-coded range.

Also note that if the PivotTables are all based on the exact same data source, refreshing one of them refreshes all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using dynamic named range to define your RawData. Set the data source of all of your pivot tables to be your dynamic named range and then all you will need to do is click data>refresh all to update all pivot tables

here is a tutorial on dynamic named ranges
http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html